# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2029'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am getting this error when I try to convert a QString to a regular python string:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2029' in position 3: ordeal not in range(128)
```

All I am doing is this:

```
str(string)
```

`string` is the QString but it then gives me that error. How can I fix this?

Comment: `str(u'\u2029'.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: @Vor why not put it into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The name `str` in Python 2.x is misleading; for historic reasons, `str is bytes` - a string of bytes instead of characters. If you try to convert a character string to a bytestring, Python uses ASCII by default. Simply use `unicode(string)` to get a character string under Python 2.x, or switch to 3.x, where `str` is actually a character string type.